# python structure _fileds_ use python function as it's number,how can it works?

Tags: python

How can I make it works like following:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *


def func(s):
    return s


class aa(structure):
    pass


aa._fields_ = [('a', c_char), ('b', func)]
a = aa()
a.a = '1'
a.b = func('2')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You have a typo in your question name, and should provide more detail on what has gone wrong with your code, and what you expected.

Comment: TypeError:second item in _fields_ tuple (index 1) must be a C type

Comment: The reason for using"('b',func)" not "('b',c_char)" is that I want  structure number having relationship with python function.